# Ubuntu 13.04 hard disk does not boot

Tags: installation, 13.04, uefi

At the moment I have just 1 hard disk in my computer, with Ubuntu 13.04 installed. It is not bootable. It is formatted with gpt, by gparted. AHCI is enabled, secure boot is not enabled.

Ubuntu live DVD shows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SAMSUNG HD154UI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags  
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat32                 boot  
 2      211MB   17.0GB  16.8GB  ext4  
 3      17.0GB  27.5GB  10.5GB  linux-swap(v1)  
 4      27.5GB  342GB   315GB   ext4  
 5      342GB   1500GB  1158GB  ext4  

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount /dev/sda
mount: can't find /dev/sda in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

Here's the content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.  
#  
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a  
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f492ea82-fae6-462a-8ba1-87a2ee68dca8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1  
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation  
UUID=1296-A193  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1  
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation  
UUID=d9dbcc8f-d124-4a46-bf4f-34fe47d2fe28 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2  
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation  
UUID=04c5c345-b31a-4481-b354-76d51b40597b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

mount can't find sda1 in fstab. I have little experience with the live DD, perhaps I am doing something wrong?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid  
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"   
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 13.04 amd64" TYPE="iso9660"   
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFIsystem" UUID="1296-A193" TYPE="vfat"   
/dev/sda2: UUID="f492ea82-fae6-462a-8ba1-87a2ee68dca8" TYPE="ext4"   
/dev/sda3: UUID="04c5c345-b31a-4481-b354-76d51b40597b" TYPE="swap"   
/dev/sda4: UUID="d9dbcc8f-d124-4a46-bf4f-34fe47d2fe28" TYPE="ext4"   
/dev/sda5: LABEL="DATA1" UUID="40f5c447-0517-48d7-a2bc-5a972ee1899e" TYPE="ext4"
```

{There is probably not a hardware problem: 2 days ago I had a working dual boot with 12.04 and windows7 on separate hard disks. I decided to put 13.04 on a 3rd hard disk, so that I could go on working with 12.04 while setting up 13.04. This didn't work out. Only after removing all other disks, Windows 7 would repair itself. Windows doesn't boot without AHCI, so AHCI must be on if I want to use the hard disk with windows later}

OK, I have repeated installation of 13.04 64 bit and let Boot-repair repair it, because boot-repair found an EFI this time. In http://paste.ubuntu.com/5680216/ you find

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda1 starts 
                   at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                   sda1 starts at sector 2048.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.04 
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab
```

That looks ok, except there is no windows disk at the moment. I have just 1 disk with a half finished ubuntu install. plain ridiculous that this should not work.

At pastebin we see:

EFI detected. Please check the options.
Partition outside the disk detected.
=================== Final advice in case of recommended repair
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/efi/.../grub*.efi file!

So the bios should boot on the grubx64.efi in sda1/efi. Is this correct? Perhaps I should do something to effect this, other than putting the harddisk as bootdisk? There is an option to load an efi in the bios, but this doesn find anything

When I boot from the harddisk I get a black screen with: reboot and select a proper device.

Mainboard: ASRock z68 Extreme3 Gen3, BIOS american megatrends

Comment: What does `sudo parted -l` give you?  Please post in question how parted sees your drives.

Comment: Bwog - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact us link at the bottom of this page and request that your two accounts are merged.  After this, you will be able to edit your question again.  Thanks.

Comment: Try sudo mount /dev/sda1
Also, fix the UUID in /etc/fstab to match the current one reported by sudo blkid (looks like it should be 782F-2623).  That mismatch confused boot-repair.

Comment: To give you some context on why your `mount` commands aren't working: when you run `mount`, it's looking at the *current* `/etc/fstab` but when you're in a live environment, `/` (and therefore `/etc/fstab`) is the live environment, not your installed copy. It contains *nothing* about your drive. To mount a drive in a live environment, you need to provide a target mount point. You also wouldn't usually mount an entire drive (`/dev/sda`) but rather a partition (eg `/dev/sda1`). This is all peripheral to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Boot Repair script has clearly failed; you most emphatically ***do*** have an EFI System Partition (ESP), and as you say, your computer does seem to be set up for an EFI-mode boot. The output you've posted (which obviates the need for the `parted` output that geezanansa requested) lacks information on what EFI boot loaders are installed -- probably because the script has inexplicably misidentified the ESP as not being an ESP. To proceed, you should mount `/dev/sda` and find all the files on that partition that end in `.efi`. For instance, you could boot a Linux live CD, mount `/dev/sda1` at `/boot/efi`, and issue the following command:

```
ls -l `find /boot/efi -iname "*.efi"`
```

Post the results here. Also, please say what happens when you try to boot the computer -- for instance, does it not boot at all, does it boot into Windows, etc.? One more command's output should also be helpful:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

Please post that along with the preceding command's output. With knowledge of the boot loaders on the ESP and what happens when you try to boot, it should be possible to offer repair suggestions.

Comment: I can mount sda2, but cant mount sda1. I think the UUID is ok, see my (edited) question.

Comment: the computer asks for a bootable medium when I try to boot from the ubuntu hard disk. When I connect the windows hard disk I can choose a windows bootloader in the F11 menu.

Answer (score 0):

The rEFIND boot manager let me boot again, see http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/, try it on a bootable medium. It showed that Ubuntu 13.04 works fine when it is found by the boot manager. It may also provide clues to what went wrong and provide a long-term solution.

Background: an attempt to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a working installation with 12.04 and windows 7 on separate hard disks went wrong. 1) Windows 7 ignored my EFI partition and made a partition in unallocated space at the very end of the disk (without informing me properly). 2) Grub2 is not perfect: it has a bug, and see http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/. 3) Boot-Repair is a program that may help these unbootable installations. It is not perfect and installed several copies of the files needed for booting. 4) Your UEFI/BIOS may not be perfect. 5) I am not perfect, I am just an end-user even though I am not completely clueless.

My thanks go to those who took an interest in my question.

I hope I did not transgress the rules with this answer. If the moderators don't like it they can just delete question and answer. This question can be closed.